# Simple complex calculus

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose I wanna solve $e^{iz}=-1-\sqrt{2}$ now that is $$iz=\ln|-1-\sqrt{2}| +i(\operatorname{Arg}(-1-\sqrt{2})+2k\pi)$$ since $-1-\sqrt{2}$ is real  $\operatorname{Arg}=0$,
so $z=-i\ln(1+\sqrt{2})+2k\pi$, $k$ is an integer.

Am I wrong? it doesn't match the solution.

Comment: But argument is $\pi$ as number is negative

Comment: I though argument is zero for ALL reals .You are right !!!!

Comment: Hope you got the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the most basic techniques of complex numbers, perhaps: put $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ , so

$$-1-\sqrt2=e^{iz}=e^{-y}\left(\cos x+i\sin x\right)\implies\begin{cases}e^{-y}\cos x=-1-\sqrt2\\{}\\e^{-y}\sin x=0\end{cases}\implies$$

$$x=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies e^{-y}(-1)^k=-1-\sqrt2\implies k\;\text{is odd, and then}$$

$$e^{-y}=1+\sqrt2\implies e^y=\frac1{1+\sqrt2}=\sqrt2-1\implies y=\log(\sqrt2-1)$$

Of course, infinite solutions as expected of something with infinite values as the complex $\;\log z\;$ ...but without using it. :)

Comment: @Math Thank you very much for the editing.

Comment: Joanpemo My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1-\sqrt{2}$ is real and *negative*, its argument is $\pi$.